# Quickchecking a nasty foreign function in Haskell(GHC)

Tags: haskell, ghc, quickcheck, memory-safety

I'd like to use Haskell's quickcheck library test some C code. The easiest way seems to be doing a  `foreign import` and write a property on top of the resulting haskell function. The problem with this is that if the C code causes a segfault or manages to corrupt memory, my tests either crash without output or do something totally unpredictable.

The second alternative is to make simple executable wrappers over the C-bits and execute them outside the testing process via `System.Process`. Needless to say, doing this requires a lot of scaffolding and serializing values, but on the other hand, it can handle segfaults.

Is there any way of making the `foreign import` strategy as safe as running an external process?

Comment: I guess you could try to do the executable wrapper in your current process, using `System.Posix.Process.forkProcess` and program the communication using Haskell.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Hmm.. That's a decent idea. Everything still needs to be serialized/deserialized, but at least I can do that in Haskell and without multiple compilation phases.

Comment: If you don't mind a hacky solution, there's libsigsegv[1] which can catch segfaults and return you to a safe(ish) point. Just set a status flag and do a `getcontext` before entering the real C function and on fault flip the flag and do a `setcontext` to return to where you `getcontext`ed. If the flag is still in its original state, everything went fine. Maybe combine with something like http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~santosh.nagarakatte/softbound/ for non-crashy errors. [1]:libsigsegv is GPL, but you don't release your tests – or do you? ;-) If that's a problem I have simpler code I can release.

Comment: (Not posting this as an answer as this is almost certainly not _"as safe as running an external process"_.)

Comment: Would running it under Valgrind be an option? That won't help on the Haskell side of things, but it'll hopefully catch those memory bugs.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I think your comment would serve as an answer if you moved it down to resolve this officially unanswered question :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the wrapper in your current process, but then use `System.Posix.Process.forkProcess` to run in safely in a process of its own, implementing the necessary communication using Haskell.

Comment: thank you for the pointer; care to expand a little? I'd be interested in knowing how this works as well. Thank you